# How to copy Folder directory including Root volume folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, robocopy

I would like to copy Recursively the full C:\Test Folder with all subdirectories including the Test folder and the folders permisions. I tried using the following commands but it only copies the files:

Powershell:

```
`Get-ChildItem -Path -Recurse C:\Test | Copy-Item -Destination F:\ -Recurse -Con
tainer`
```

Robocopy:

```
robocopy C:\Test F:\ /s /e
```

Comment: Just specify the target directory. You're not copying from C:\Test to F:, you're copying from C:\Test to F:\Test, and you need to tell it that.

Comment: `Get-Item C:\test | copy-item -destination F:\ -Recurse` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy has several options to preserve properties, but if you want to preserve it all use "/copyall":

`robocopy "c:\test" "f:\test" /copyall /e`

Also note that using a trailing slash for folder names is not allowed since it escapes the quote. These are good:

```
robocopy "c:\test" "f:" /copyall /e
robocopy "c:\test" "f:\test" /copyall /e
```

These are bad:

```
robocopy "c:\test" "f:\" /copyall /e
robocopy "c:\test" "f:\test\" /copyall /e
```